# "omni"-prefixed word for "all-hearing"

Tags: single-word-requests, analogy, latin

Is there an adjective that begins with the prefix *omni* that means *all-hearing?* I thought that an aural counterpart to *omnipresent*, *omnipotent*, and *omniscient* must exist, but after a few minutes of Googling, I've failed to find any synonyms for *all-hearing.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The logical construction would be along the lines of omnaudient (given the Latin verb "to listen" is "audio") but I've never seen it used.

Comment: "Omniaudient" is indeed the word for which I was looking. Thanks!

Comment: "Audio" means "I listen/hear". "Audire" means "to listen/hear".

Comment: Correct.  That's Latin, though, and this board's english-focused; I didn't think that it'd help matters too much to go into the full conjugation of audio -ire -ibi -itus

Comment: Ok, but is it spelled "omnaudient" as in the answer, or "omniaudient" as in the OP's comment?

Comment: Both would be fine under the usual ways of constructing Latinate words, but I'd prefer the un-elided form "omniaudient" as it's more likely to be understood.

Answer (score 1):

Omniaural? (Maybe this just means, "can be heard everywhere".)

Comment: Actually I think this would mean "all ears". :-)

Answer (score 0):

"Omniaudient" used in "Midnight's Children" Salman Rushdie 1981.

Comment: This answer would be better with a reference to an accepted reference like a dictionary

Comment: Instances of _omniaudient_ go back at least as far as "[A Christian Creed: or, Summary of Truth Faith](https://books.google.com/books?id=kNpbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA11&dq=%22omniaudient%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8lfLO4MnYAhUp_IMKHcHECacQ6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q=%22omniaudient%22&f=false)" (1736): "The Creator, Preserver, and Sustainer of all Creation: Ever omnipresent, omnipercipient, omniscient, **omniaudient**, and the prescient, ordinant, and preordinant Director, and the universal sole sovereign Lord and supream Governor of all, ..."